# How to increment value when one of row have NULL value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "Total Product" that one of some rows has NULL values for the total product. I'd like to create a query that can increment all value even it is NULL. This is what table

```
| Date      | Total Product Added | 
|---------- |-------------------- | 
| 18/07/01  |         100         |
| 18/05/01  |         300         |
| 18/01/01  |        1000         |
```

this what table that i was expected

```
| Date      | Total Product Added |
|---------- |-------------------- |
| 18/07/01  |        1400         |
| 18/06/01  |        1300         |
| 18/05/01  |        1300         |
| 18/04/01  |        1000         |
| 18/03/01  |        1000         |
| 18/01/01  |        1000         |
```

i already used this query but the result not like i want:

```
select
    date,
    sum(total_product_added) over (order by date asc) as total_product,

from
    sold_product

group by
    date,
    total_product
order by
    date_created desc
```

when i have used that query, this is the result:

```
| Date      | Total Product Added |
|---------- |-------------------- |
| 18/07/01  |        1400         |
| 18/05/01  |        1300         |
| 18/01/01  |        1000         |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.dte,
       sum(total_product_added) over (order by gs.dte asc) as total_product
from (select generate_series(min(sp.date), max(sp.date), interval '1 day') as dte
      from sold_product sp
     ) gs left join
     sold_product sp
     on sp.date = gs.dte
order by gs.dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9c2cd3cd585dae457db972a86f33c52b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: i can't use this, is it something error in that query?

Comment: @AnggaPrasetiyo . . . The table alias went in the wrong place.

Comment: i have use the last one, but the result like this
`
| Date      | Total Product Added |
| ---------- |-------------------- |
| 18/07/01  |        1400         |
| 18/06/01  |        1400         |
| 18/05/01  |        1300         |
| 18/04/01  |        1400         |
| 18/03/01  |        1400         |
| 18/02/01  |        1400         |
| 18/01/01  |        1000         |
`

Comment: @AnggaPrasetiyo . . . I made a small fix and added a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, it is really helpfull
what if i change interval to 1 month?
when i try change the date `2018-01-07` to `2018-02-07' and change interval to `1 month`, the result like this [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3f6ee0005e87e7b7b49425eb4fdbdc29)

Comment: @AnggaPrasetiyo . . . If you have a new question (say about months), then you should ask as a *new* question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE:

```
select
    date,
    sum(COALESCE(total_product_added, 0)) over (order by date asc) as total_product,    
from
    sold_product    
group by
    date,
    total_product
order by
    date_created desc
```

Comment: when i have used this, the result still like this:
```
| Date      | Total Product Added |
|---------- |-------------------- |
| 18/07/01  |        1400         |
| 18/05/01  |        1300         |
| 18/01/01  |        1000         |
```

Comment: How strange... try with ```case when total_product_added IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE total_product_added```

Comment: What is the data type?

Comment: total_product_added is integer.
but i can't get the right result if i use `case when total_product_added IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE total_product_added`

Comment: why not? can you give an example?